# Excel vba to find a word then perform vlookup

Tags: excel, vba, find, vlookup

I'm trying to write vba code in excel to do the following sequence of actions:

- Determine whether a specific "word" is contained in cell W8 of sheet1;
- If the "word" is found, then;
- Search the range A3:A171 on sheet2 for the "Word2" contained in cell W7 of 
  sheet1,
- If this "Word2" is found in the range, then
- Cell V3 on sheet1 must display the value in column B of the row that the 
  "Word2" was found.

I've been trying to achieve this with various vlookup and find function combinations with no luck (i'm a newbie).

Really appreciate anyone who can help. This has certainly been giving me a headache!

Let me know if you need more info or the above steps aren't clear.

Sooo..... this where I'm at so far with the VBA code. Keep in mind I want it to perform the exact function that Loocid has provided below....

```
Sub IF_FUNCTION()
    If InStr(W8.Value, "Word1") > 0 Then
        Range("V3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B3:B171"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("W7").Value, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A3:A171"), 0), "")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: why vba, and not just a formula?

Comment: I'll need to run through many variants of the above sequences to provide different answers to cell V3, so i thought vba would be the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Scott, you can do this without VBA.

Try this formula in V3:

```
=IF(W8<>"word", INDEX(sheet2!B3:B171, MATCH(W7, sheet2!A3:A171, 0)), "")
```

Comment: =IF(W8<>"word", INDEX(sheet2!B3:B171, MATCH(W7, sheet2!A3:A171, 0)), "")

Comment: Ah yep, missed that the value was on the same sheet. So its working for you?

Comment: Thanks! I modified it slightly to include the sheet2! identifier after INDEX, but this is exactly what I need in VBA. I want to run variations of this code in the same cell, so that's the reason why i though VBA  would be best.

Comment: Is anybody able to help me change the above function into VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub IF_FUNCTION()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

With ws

    If InStr(1, .Range("W8"), "Word1") > 0 Then
        .Range("V3") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ws2.Range("B3:B171"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Range("W7"), ws2.Range("A3:A171"), 0), 1)
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks QHarr. I just ended up using the following. It works, but do you think there would be any issues with speed etc. the more times i use it?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Address = "$W$8" Then
    Range("V3").Value =[IF(W8<>"Word1",INDEX(sheet2!B3:B171,MATCH(W7,Sheet2!A3:A171,0)),"")]
  End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help Loocid, wouldn't have been able to do it with out that function.

Comment: what do you mean?